# Why does zurb ink add extra padding on td

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, zurb-ink

i am using the responsive email framework from zurb ink. The issue i have is that Zurb ink likes to add 10px padding at the bottom of the td, when i override this with 
    style="padding:0 on the td,
 it works for most email clients except outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013. Is there any ways to override it in these email clients.

I have also tried this
    style="padding:0 !important" on the td
and going through it by using a class as well.

Answer (score 0):

td's by default have no padding. Here is the CSS

````
```
table, tr, td {
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
```
````

Are you referring to block-grid td's? Those have 10px bottom-padding. `<p>` tags have bottom-margin. Do you have a live example we can see to help you more?

Comment: Yes i am referring to the block grid td